# VS2012 Debugger will not open browser when debugging ASP MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug an ASP MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012. However, once the code compiles the debugger stops completely, never bringing up the browser. I am able to run ASP.Net projects just fine from this computer, however this project doesn't seem to want to work.
With this project if i click on IIS Express in Notification area so it shows my website and if i click on it so then it opens up my site on browser but by default on debugging with Visual Studio it doesn't open.

I also tried to set my start up project but this also does not work????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this setting in your web project's settings and ensure it's not set to "don't open a page"

[image]

Comment: From where can i find these settings??